# Which one of three styles is the most correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, nouns, adjectives

which one of three styles is the most correct ?

first example:
1- The algorithm's running time.
2- The algorithm running time.
3- The running time of the algorithm.

second example:
1- The Transmitter's energy consumption.
2- The Transmitter energy consumption.
3- The energy consumption of the transmitter.

Honestly, I am confused about them :), I am not sure what the difference is. Is there any grammar for such situation? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The most common use of the _-'s_ possessive is for people: _Bill's brother, his job, my sister's dog_. The _of_ possessive is more common with non-human noun phrases and especially with complex noun phrases: _the energy consumption of the transmitter, the running time of the algorithm,_ etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to judge context properly with sentence fragments, but in both of your examples, 1 and 3 are ok while 2 is less grammatically correct (since running time and energy consumption belong to the algorithm and transmitter respectively).

Also there's no need to capitalize the T in transmitter unless it's the proper name for the object.

Comment: No; there's nothing 'less grammatical' per se about using an attributive noun rather than a possessive construction.  As you say, here '[i]t's difficult to judge context properly with sentence fragments'; (1) almost always and (3) almost as commonly would be used (only) when referring to a specific algorithm / transmitter, whereas (2) would be the more usual choice for more general statements.